# Ruby on Rails Mobile Application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mobile

I am trying to develop a Ruby on Rails application that will detect the client  i.e the mobile (browser) that connects to the server and render the appropriate layout. 
I tried using the following link but still not able to connect it. Any suggestions ?

http://www.arctickiwi.com/blog/mobile-enable-your-ruby-on-rails-site-for-small-screens

I am using Opera Mini Emulator to test the application.

Comment: That looks like a really excellent article, thanks for linking it. :) Where are you getting stuck? Do your logfiles show attempts to access the mobile content? If you add some logging to your browser detection, can you tell when the Opera Mini emulator is connecting vs when a desktop browser connects?

Comment: What do you mean by "not able to connect to it"? Sounds more like a network issue to me. If detection of a mobile browser doesn't work, it should at least show the same content as your desktop browser.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The most elegant solution for this I've seen is to do two things: recognize mobile users based on user-agent in the request and use a custom Rails mime type to respond with, allowing custom HTML templates for mobile users.

Define a custom 'mobile' Rails MIME type in `config/initializers/mime_types.rb` that's just HTML:

```
Mime::Type.register_alias "text/html", :mobile
```

Add a helper/filter to respond to mobile users:

```
def mobile_user_agent?
  @mobile_user_agent ||= ( request.env["HTTP_USER_AGENT"] && request.env["HTTP_USER_AGENT"][/(Mobile\/.+Safari)/] )
end
```

then..

```
before_filter :handle_mobile

def handle_mobile
  request.format = :mobile if mobile_user_agent?
end
```

Make custom mobile template:

```
app/views/users/show.html.erb => app/views/users/show.mobile.erb
```

Dispatch mobile or regular in controllers:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html { }   # Regular stuff
  format.mobile { } # other stuff
end
```

Comment: Great suggestions -- I'm doing this approach using mobile_fu for the recognition.

Comment: While this is a common approach, I'd actually suggest not being this aggressive. You may want to detect that the user has an iphone and suggest at the top of the page that they use your mobile interface which has a separate hostname (m, mobile, touch, etc..). This lets you offer both an optimizied experience while still allowing iphone users to have access to your actual site with the full featureset.

Comment: Matt has a good point here.  The mobile/iphone experience is different  enough it can make sense to have the context of an entirely separate site/hostname.